# Chrome Developer Tools not displaying (Version 51.0.2704.84 (64-bit))

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I'm no longer able to access my Developer Tools in Mac Chrome (Version 51.0.2704.84 (64-bit)). This is the latest update for Chrome. CMD-OPTION-I and View > Developer > Developer Tools provides no result.

Is anyone else having this issue? Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, I did the following:

1. Made a backup of /Users//Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default.
2. Delete the Chrome App
3. Deleted the root Chrome folder /Users//Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/
4. Downloaded and reinstalled the latest version of Chrome (Tried a simple update before previous steps, but didn't work)
5. Removed defaults from the new install
6. Copied back up of default content into new Default folder

Dev tools are now functioning again.

Answer (score 1):

Try go to `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default\Local Storage` and delete these two files :

chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage

chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage-journal

Or purge all your Google Chrome User Data and reinstall Chrome.

Comment: Please elaborate, how would that help in this scenario?

Comment: I already tried deleting the local storage files based on the recommendation of another post (http://superuser.com/questions/439353/google-chrome-developer-tools-not-displaying).  This did not have any impact.